# the import com.viewpagerindicator cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I am a newbie to android. the question maybe silly for you, so forgive me.
Now i am receiving an android project and open it in ADT.

When open the project there are two errors in two java files, which is `the import com.viewpagerindicator cannot be resolved` in the Problems. I have searched with google and find it's using [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). and also the jar name is `android-support-v4.jar`. I checked the project `libs` folder there is `android-support-v4.jar` and it's also in the `Android Private Libraries`.

I thought maybe it's not configured in the build path. so i checked the `Java Build Path` tab in the project Properties window, it's also in the Libraries tab. screenshot is as below:
[image]

Am i missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the part about "Including it in your project" https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: do you get any error in cosole when you import project.. please see any error in cosnole not in logcat ..if found any error then paste it here

Comment: @andrewww you cannot run the project, since there is some obvious errors :[

Comment: while importing project if anyone made any mistake then it gives error in console. I am asking about that. and I knew it, runtime error gives in Logcat ..I am asking about console error

Comment: @andrewww `the import com.viewpagerindicator cannot be resolved in the Problems.` this is the error message from the Problems console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the project as an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html), it seems you haven't done this.

From the "[Including In Your Project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)" section

> Android-ViewPagerIndicator is presented as an Android library project. A standalone JAR is not possible due to the theming capabilities offered by the indicator widgets.
>
> You can include this project by [referencing it as a library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) in Eclipse or ant.

1. Download all the source of the project, save it somewhere on your PC.
2. In Eclipse click *File/Import/Existing Android Code into Workspace* and choose this folder.
3. In your project click *Project Properties/Android* and in the *Library* section choose this project.

Comment: Yes, it works. But it seems there is a conflict with the previous one.it says `Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list`

Comment: I am talking about this error . delete your v4 lib file one of lib and keep same file in both library project and your working project

Comment: Delete either the one in `libs/` of your project or the one in `libs/` of the library project, it's a common error. Or keep them the same version as mentioned above by @andrewww